# getParcelableExtra() crushing after Starting activity when passing an object

Tags: android, class, object, android-intent, parcelable

Im trying to pass an object between activities but my app crushes:

This is my class (the object im passing through the intent):

```
public class item implements Parcelable {
private int id;
private String title;
private String desc;
private double lat;
private double lon;
private String pub;
private int p;
private int n;

public item(int id, String title, String desc, double lat, double lon, String pub, int p, int n) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.pub = pub;
    this.p = p;
    this.n = n;
}
}
```

I call the intent with an object (the object is within a list):

```
Intent.putExtra("thing",markers.get(i));
startActivity(Intent);
```

And im getting the Extra at the destination activity:

```
item item = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("thing");
```

My logcat:

```
08-10 23:47:21.009: W/dalvikvm(30373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4101b2a0)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.ItemView}: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.example.free.item
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2081)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1217)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.example.free.item
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2086)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4435)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at com.example.free.ItemView.onCreate(ItemView.java:21)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
08-10 23:47:21.009: E/AndroidRuntime(30373):    ... 11 more
```

**Edit**:

My whole class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class item implements Parcelable {
private int id;
private String title;
private String desc;
private double lat;
private double lon;
private String pub;
private int p;
private int n;

public item(int id, String title, String desc, double lat, double lon, String pub, int p, int n) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.pub = pub;
    this.p = p;
    this.n = n;
}

public item(Parcel in) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<item> CREATOR 
= new Parcelable.Creator<item>() {
public item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
return new item(in);
}

public item[] newArray(int size) {
return new item[size];
}
};

}
```

(I removed all the getters and setters for less code)

Comment: `Parcelable` protocol requires a `Parcelable.Creator` object called  CREATOR on class `item`.

Comment: I didnt really understand.. what do I have to do with the class?

Comment: Sample code for Parcelable [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: So, I just have to add `Parcelable.Creator` to my class? (item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs page on Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Unlike `Serializable`, it's not enough to just mark your class as `Parcelable` with the interface. You have to do a few more things:

1. You need to implement the `writeToParcel` method as well as a constructor that takes in a `Parcel` object as its only argument. Note how these two are constructed in the sample code on that page; be careful that the order you write data to the Parcel in `writeToParcel` is the same order you read them out in that constructor.
2. You need to add the following inside your Item class:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Item> CREATOR 
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Item>() {
    public Item createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Item(in);
    }

    public Item[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Item[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: Ive already added this. I've now edited the question and added my class. Is it right?

Comment: update: Its now working, but the data doesnt seem to pass. I mean, the variables return null!

Comment: @NirPes how did you solve the problem? as i am still having it